# How to set typeface from ExternalStorage and multi font

Tags: environment, typeface

I've created a list of fonts in `ExternalStorageDirectory` and I'm saving it to :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How do I set the typeface in textView from fonts to myFolder?

This code only sets typeface to one font in a directory

```
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File name = new File(root_sd + "/myFolder/");
File[] files = name.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(files[i].getPath());
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    textView.setTextSize(20);

}
```

Comment: your code is working as you said. It's set last text font. Then what is the problem you faced?

Comment: This Is Set Typeface For One Font But Im have Multi Font To Set Typeface ...

Comment: If you have multiple textView then you can set multiple typeface for multiple textView.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sample for using 3 different typeface in 3 different textView based on your code. You can try this instead of removing the loop.

```
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File name = new File(root_sd + "/myFolder/");
File[] files = name.listFiles();

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(files[0].getPath());
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
textView.setTextSize(20);

Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromFile(files[1].getPath());
textView2.setTypeface(typeface2);
textView2.setTextSize(20);

Typeface typeface3 = Typeface.createFromFile(files[2].getPath());
textView3.setTypeface(typeface3);
textView3.setTextSize(20);
```

Comment: I want to set up typeface from 10 font in one textView  for example http://s9.picofile.com/file/8344911850/11.png

Comment: Then you need to handle another list that contains all typefaces in one list. For 0 index item, you can get typeface from 0 indexes of the list.

Answer (score 0):

i'm set list of fonts With code :

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPersianFonts(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File name = new File(root_sd + "/myFolder/");
            File[] files = name.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                list.add( files[i].getName() );
            }
            return list;

    } catch  (Exception e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now have get typeface from list and set to textView??

Comment: Yes. You can try this.